# What information is lost when you view only a piece of broken hologram?

Tags: optics, interference, hologram

When a hologram is broken into pieces, you can still see the whole object from any piece of them, but I am wondering what information is lost in each of them, does the hologram images look the same from all of them? Or it looks like viewing from different angles? Or it is just certain spatial frequency components are missing in each piece? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For 2d holographic plates, it's essentially like looking through a smaller window onto the same scene. You don't have as many views of the subject.

Comment: thanks, but other than the viewing angles, I guess the resolution also becomes lower as others suggested in the answer, is it correct?

Comment: I haven't observed loss of resolution. It's a smaller aperture onto the scene, so the image is dimmer. It's harder to resolve a dimmer image.

Comment: thank you so much for providing the answer based on your real experience in experiments! I guess the hologram plate records the angular spectrum of the real object, and different areas record lights coming from different directions from the object, so with one piece the view is limited, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately what you lose is resolution.  If you cut the hologram in half the image becomes have the size.  But suppose you then magnify the image to return it to its original size.  And suppose you repeat that process of cutting and magnifying.  Eventually the image would become "pixelated" or blurry.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you will lose resolution as the effective window gets smaller. If you are viewing the image directly, then the limiting factor for resolution is the size of the pupil of the eye which is probably much smaller than the piece of hologram. (Slightly more complex as you look with two eyes.)